# I'm getting the values from the table and while comparing I'm getting words split completely

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Testing\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.navigate().to("https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")).click();
driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Testing6738788");
driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("test@123");
driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]/img")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Angelfish')]//preceding-sibling::td//a")).click();
List<WebElement> tablelist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Catalog']//tr"));

for(int i = 0; i < tablelist.size(); i++)
{
    String gotvalues = tablelist.get(i).getText();
    System.out.println("Values got from the table  " +gotvalues);
    // Here im using split function but no luck
    String[] splitword = gotvalues.split(" ");
    for(String words : splitword)
    {
        System.out.println("Got single words from the split " + words);
        // I want to compare the Large Angelfish value from the output
        if(words.equalsIgnoreCase("Large Angelfish"))
        {
            System.out.println("Element present " + words);
        }
    }
}
```

Words should be split as "Item ID" -EST-1. I'm facing an issue with the description. The complete word is not getting displayed. How to write code to get item ID, product ID, and description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without String Array also you can verify.Try this code see if this help.Take input from keyboard.You have to type both values in console Like `EST-1` then Enter and Then `Large Angelfish` and its compared later.Try Now.

```
 Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    String textID= scan.nextLine(); //Enter ID Here
    String textDesc= scan.nextLine();//Enter Desc Here
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Testing\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.navigate().to("https://jpetstore.cfapps.io/catalog");
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Sign In')]")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("Testing6738788");
            driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("test@123");
            driver.findElement(By.id("login")).click();

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='SidebarContent']/a[contains(@href,'FISH')]/img")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[contains(text(),'Angelfish')]//preceding-sibling::td//a")).click();
       List<WebElement> tablelist = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='Catalog']//tr/td"));
       System.out.println(tablelist.size());

     for(int i=0;i<tablelist.size();i++)
    {
        String gotvalues = tablelist.get(0).getText();
        String gotvaluesdesc = tablelist.get(2).getText();

       // System.out.println("Values got from the table  " +gotvalues  );
        if(gotvalues.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(textID) && gotvaluesdesc.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(textDesc))

        {
            System.out.println("Element present ID: " + gotvalues + " Desc :" + gotvaluesdesc);
            break;
        }
```

Comment: I need both Item ID and description for that one above code doesn't work.

Comment: I have updated the answer as per Your requirements.Please try this and let me know.I have changed the xpath a bit and remaining scripts are same.

Comment: Thanks for your effort .my queries i need to give input as Item Id and description then in the code it has to compare two values and in report, i need to generate those two values.

Comment: Updated code is not working .I need to create method for the page like table(String xpath,Int item id,String expectedvalue,int descriptionid,String expectedvalueofdescription) above one i tried not working.If you have idea.please revert me back.

Comment: Item id value I need to read it from Excel and store it in one value and web application values also I need to store it one value.then I need to compare the two values.if you know the solution please help me on this

Comment: I think I had answer your first post.But you haven’t accepted my answer yet.If you need any further help post another question in this foram.OP who available will help you.

Comment: But your code is not working .for that reason i haven't accepted.

Comment: What errors are you getting?you should post otherwise how people know?It is working on my laptop.share the error here.

Comment: Application itself is not launching

Comment: Have you read my post.Have to type two values one by one and then press enter.Please read my last updated code what I said because your console asking for values to enter then will application launch.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to compare the table data, you need to modify your xPath little to fetch the data effectively so that you can avoid the splitting part and you can compare the data easily.

Try the below code :

```
String xPath = "//div[@id='Catalog']//tr";
List<WebElement> tableList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath));
System.out.println("Item ID\t\tProduct ID\t\tDescription\t\tList Price\t\tOther");
System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
for(int i=1;i<tableList.size();i++) {
    // Below line fetches/stores each table data as column wise
    List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
    for(int j=0;j<listData.size();j++) {
        // Printing the column data
        System.out.print(listData.get(j).getText()+"\t\t");
    }
    System.out.println();
}

// As per the above output, description is in the 3rd(2nd index) column so you can fetch that with the index number 2.
for(int i=1;i<tableList.size();i++) {
    List<WebElement> listData = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xPath+"["+(i+1)+"]/td"));
    if(listData.get(2).getText().trim().equals("Large Angelfish")) {
        System.out.println("=> 'Large Angelfish' is Matching...");
    }

    if(listData.get(2).getText().trim().equals("Large Angelfish")) {
        System.out.println("=> 'Small Angelfish' is Matching...");
    }
}
```

If you execute the above code, it will print output as below :

```
Item ID     Product ID      Description     List Price      Other
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EST-1       FI-SW-01        Large Angelfish     $16.50      Add to Cart     
EST-2       FI-SW-01        Small Angelfish     $16.50      Add to Cart
```

In the above output, Description column number is 3 so you can substitute an index number in the below line for the corresponding column :

```
listData.get(2).getText().trim().equals("Large Angelfish")
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: @Testing Passion, is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your effort .my queries I need to give input as Item Id and description then in the code it has to compare two values and in report, I need to generate those two values.

Comment: for `item id`, insert `0` and for `description`, insert `2` in the if condition of `listData.get(insert here)` and for taking an input, use the scanner or buffered reader

Comment: When im creating method its not working.please find updated code i have replaced with your code.

Comment: Item id value I need to read it from Excel and store it in one value and web application values also I need to store it one value.then I need to compare the two values.if you know the solution please help me on this